# Error passing value from HTML to PHP file

Tags: php, html

Error even after using 'isset'

This is my html file:

```
<form action="php/login.php" method="POST">
      <label for="sel1">Pilih Payroll:</label>
      <select name="tipe">
            <option value="kl">Karyawan Lapangan</option>
            <option value="kk">Karyawan Kantor</option>
      </select>  
      <input type="text" id="username" class="fadeIn second" name="username" placeholder="username">
      <input type="password" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="password" placeholder="password">
      <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Log In">
</form>
```

this is my php file:

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    }

    if(isset($_POST['password'])){
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    }

    if(isset($_POST['tipe'])){
    $tipe = $_POST['tipe'];
    }
```

i get this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: username in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\payroll\php\login.php on line 16
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: username in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\payroll\php\login.php on line 25
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: password in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\payroll\php\login.php on line 26
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: tipe in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\payroll\php\login.php on line 27
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: username in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\payroll\php\login.php on line 31
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: password in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\payroll\php\login.php on line 31
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: tipe in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\payroll\php\login.php on line 31
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: username in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\payroll\php\login.php on line 33
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: password in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\payroll\php\login.php on line 33
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: tipe in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\payroll\php\login.php on line 33

Comment: Did you checked what your ```$_POST``` contains before if condition?

Comment: are you accessing your php without submitting your form? You are only defining your variables if their `$_POST` is set, which would be why they are undefined later.

Comment: if i'm not using 'isset' the $username and $password variable work just fine but the $tipe get the same error, the reason why im using 'isset' is because $tipe variable wont pass the value (sorry for bad english)

Comment: You are not show the line that is causing the error... `C:\xampp\htdocs\payroll\php\login.php on lines 16, 25, 26, 27, 31 and 33`

Comment: Are you submitting the form with empty data if so then `add required validations for input fields` or are you accessing php directly as @Sean is saying?

Comment: Did you init all that variables before `if`? e.g. `$username = '';`